# PyQGIS signal - crsChanged

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, qgis-3, qt

I'm trying to connect to the crsChanged signal in PyQGIS and each time I try to connect to it, I get the following error:

```
() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

The relevant pieces of code are:

```
self.project = QgsProject.instance()
self.project.crsChanged.connect(self.crsFx)

def crsFx(self):
    print('Changing Crs')
    self.crs = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().destinationCrs().authid()
    print(self.crs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small example works for me. It is simpler to user project instance.

```
def cc():
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    print(project.crs().authid())

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.crsChanged.connect(cc)
```

Comment: Excellent @Zoltan. That worked great. Just wondering how did you figure that out? From the documentation, I was unable to. Thanks

Comment: Years and the experience ... :)